# Is there a way to destroy a label of function from one class to another in tkinter?

Tags: python, html, tkinter

I am trying to make a Quiz game application using tkinter. I am facing a problem. Can anyone please help me

```
def incorrect(self):
        
    global lb
        
    lb=Label(self.root, text="Incorrect",font='50',height='1')

    lb.place(x=300,y=480)

def qn2(self):

     global l2,bc,bs,bp,bne,total,l,lb

     l1.destroy()

     bg.destroy()

     bv.destroy()

     bf.destroy()

     bn.destroy()

     l.destroy()

     lb.destroy()
```

Error:

```
lb.destroy()

NameError: name 'lb' is not defined
```

Can anyone please help me. Thanks!

Comment: If you are using class, why don't you do ```self.lb``` instead of making it global

Comment: if i do that it will show error like :   self.lb.destroy()
                                                      AttributeError: 'Questions' object has no attribute 'lb'

Comment: you have to to ```self.lb=Label(..)```. Make it a part of the class so that it can be used anywhere

Comment: Just because you write `global x` inside a function doesn't make the `x` global variable exist. It only tells Python "`x` inside this function means the global `x`, if any, and not anything local". The equivalent thing happens with class attributes; you can only `self.lb.destroy()` if something assigned a value to `self.lb` before. Either way, you need to think about what happens if `incorrect` is **not** called before `qn2`.

Comment: This is how gave it and it showed that error                                      
  self.lb=Label(self.root, text="Incorrect",font='50',height='1')
  self.lb.place(x=300,y=480)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi you can define ld and l outside the def function and it would work fine

````
You can make code bocks with this ```
````

Like this

```
def incorrect():
        
    global lb
        
    lb.place(x=300,y=480)

def qn2():

     global l2,bc,bs,bp,bne,total,l,lb

     l1.destroy()

     bg.destroy()

     bv.destroy()

     bf.destroy()

     bn.destroy()

     l.destroy()

     lb.destroy() 
lb=Label(self.root, text="Incorrect",font='50',height='1')
```

You can remove self

Comment: You can place lables by calling function later

Comment: Yeah! I tried but still it is not working

Comment: It is ```Label```

Comment: There are lot of errors. It is ```def``` not ```Def```, function is defined as ```lableplacer()``` but called as ```Lableplacer()```

Comment: hey it actually worked! thanks @new_to_code    and thanks to all